# Have Mercurial use a custom merge tool for its own merges

Tags: mercurial, merge

Mercurial docs about what mercurial does when it has to do a 3way merge:

> By default, Mercurial will attempt to do a classic 3-way merge on text
>   files internally before trying to use an external tool.

When it invokes the external tool, that is always a "manual merge".

Not all merge tools are created equally, and as it turns out my merge tool of choice (Araxis Merge), is often able to do an automatic merge of 3 files, where mercurial's internal merge tool was not able to do so.

This leads to the scenario of big merges where maybe a bunch of files merge cleanly, done by hg's internal mergetool,  and then some other files do not merge cleanly *but could have if hg would let me specify its mergetool*. I find this to make big merges very inefficient, as you need to context switch a lot: hg pops up my merge tool, I think "oh darn, conflict", to then realize "oh wait, theres no conflict at all"

I wonder if I'm missing something here, or if there is really no way to make hg able to use a custom merge tool for its automatic attempts at doing merges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a switch to make Araxis Merge close itself automatically if it can auto-merge. I looked at the [command line reference](http://www.araxis.com/merge/command_line.html) and their [SCM integration document](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#Mercurial), but I'm actually not sure what switch it would be. You'll have to experiment yourself.

From Mercurial's point of view there is no such thing as a "manual merge". Mercurial tries to merge internally first (the so-called "premerge" step) and if that fails it looks for an external tool. The merge can still be **fully automatic** if that tool exists with an exit code of zero (successful exit). Mercurial will then consider the merge successful and go on to the next file. Depending on the tool, you wont notice this at all: Mercurial just runs the tool in the background and you're only prompted for action when there is a serious merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom merge tool with Mercurial.  `help merge-tools` shows the order in which tools are chosen to run:

```
1. If a tool has been specified with the --tool option to merge or
   resolve, it is used.  If it is the name of a tool in the merge-tools
   configuration, its configuration is used. Otherwise the specified tool
   must be executable by the shell.
2. If the "HGMERGE" environment variable is present, its value is used and
   must be executable by the shell.
3. If the filename of the file to be merged matches any of the patterns in
   the merge-patterns configuration section, the first usable merge tool
   corresponding to a matching pattern is used. Here, binary capabilities
   of the merge tool are not considered.
4. If ui.merge is set it will be considered next. If the value is not the
   name of a configured tool, the specified value is used and must be
   executable by the shell. Otherwise the named tool is used if it is
   usable.
5. If any usable merge tools are present in the merge-tools configuration
   section, the one with the highest priority is used.
6. If a program named "hgmerge" can be found on the system, it is used -
   but it will by default not be used for symlinks and binary files.
7. If the file to be merged is not binary and is not a symlink, then
   "internal:merge" is used.
8. The merge of the file fails and must be resolved before commit.
```

More information can be found in `help config` - look for `merge-tools` and `merge-patterns`